# What is the effect on baseboard heating capacity of running the return pipe within the enclosure?

Tags: heating, baseboard, radiator

Baseboard radiators can be installed with the return pipe running within the baseboard enclosure itself. While this is a configuration explicitly supported by manufacturers **I can't find any hard data on what effect this will have on the rated heating capacity**.

I have read on internet forums general statements that it might reduce the heat output by "25%" but without any official documentation or manufacturer's information to back that up.

I've looked at documentation from a # of different manufacturers (samples below) and don't see this information. They DO publish tables of heat output at various average supply water temperatures but neglect the different piping configurations.

Even a single solid example would be useful (better than nothing) even though baseboard performance does vary a lot.

---

The examples below are just that - I'm not asking about any particular product.

Here's an example of Slant/Fin documentation regarding this type of installation:

[image]

([source](https://www.slantfin.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/01/Baseboard-Installation-Instructions-103.pdf))

And from Synergy another example of how the physical install is provided for + an example of their heat output data:

[image]

> Optional “easy-glide” cradles are available for return piping
> installations.

([source](https://www.h-mac.com/product-catalogs/designline/DesignLine-Synergy-Brochure.pdf))

[image]

(same [source](https://www.h-mac.com/product-catalogs/designline/DesignLine-Synergy-Brochure.pdf))

Tables like the above are very common - what I'd love to see would be a second table showing the values with the second pipe in place.

Details which I imagine would be important is whether the pipe runs above or below the fins, and whether the bare pipe or the finned pipe carries the return water.

Comment: No reason to think it would *reduce* heat output. Take away the fins for a second - would you expect less heat from twice as much hot pipe? The finned pipe radiates better, but you still have more hot pipe in the room...

Comment: @Ecnerwal the discussions I've read claim that the pipe affects the airflow (presumably reducing it) through the unit as the reason for affecting the output. I don't know if this is true or not